# PHP MySQL: Update incremental where condition can be duplicated

Tags: php, mysql

I have a statement like this:

```
UPDATE `MyTable` 
SET point = point + 1 
WHERE (mySubject = 'MATHEMATICS' AND myGrade = '100') OR 
      (mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75') OR 
      (mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75')
```

And I want the table to be updated to:

```
MATHEMATICS | 100 |  1
PHYSICS     | 75  |  2
```

instead of

```
PHYSICS     | 75  | 1
```

The reason why there is a duplicated 'PHYSICS' condition is because I get this information from another function. 
And I want to know if I can increment PHYSICS point by two if the other function pass me PHYSICS 2 time.

Is there a way to do this in one connection instead of calling the UPDATE 3 times :

```
UPDATE `MyTable` SET point = point + 1 WHERE mySubject = 'MATHEMATICS' AND myGrade = '100'
UPDATE `MyTable` SET point = point + 1 WHERE mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75'
UPDATE `MyTable` SET point = point + 1 WHERE mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75'
```

Comment: Your question is not clear in my eyes.

Comment: While the condition is duplicated, your query looks fine. Are you sure you have both "MATHEMATICS" and "PHYSICS" in your table?

Comment: The `(mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75')` is duplicated because you're generating the query using a function (and you want to increment the point count by 2), right?

Comment: why use same condition twice in the query, (mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75') OR 
      (mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75')

Comment: Where are the 3 updates?

Comment: There is not logic for the SQL to set Physics to 2..
It will take Physics row only once for update not twice to make it 2..

Comment: Hi Svetlio, in that case, I assume it isn't possible to execute the increment without calling update to physics twice, if I don't want to change the SET point = point + 1 to SET point = point + 2? Hi, irrelephant, Yes, it's duplicated because it's generated by a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make UPDATE to table it takes each row ONCE ONLY..
So it wont generate 2 updates for the Physics...

```
    UPDATE `MyTable` 
SET point = point + 1 
WHERE (mySubject = 'MATHEMATICS' AND myGrade = '100') OR 
      (mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75') OR 
      (mySubject = 'PHYSICS' AND myGrade = '75')
```

This query say's to the SQL ..
UPDATE for me all rows in MyTable WHERE (case a) or (case b) or (case c)

SQL takes Mathematics and at case a its OK and updated.
Then it takes Physics and at case b they are OK and updated and then sql FINISH because there no more ROWS at table..

You have to make 2 seperated updates to do your job..

```
UPDATE `MyTable` SET point = point + 1 WHERE mySubject = 'MATHEMATICS';
UPDATE `MyTable` SET point = point + 2 WHERE mySubject = 'PHYSICS';
```

Or you can use CASE

```
UPDATE  `MyTable` SET point = 
        CASE
        WHEN mySubject = 'MATHEMATICS' THEN
                (point+1)
        WHEN mySubject = 'PHYSICS' THEN
                (point+2)
        END
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the clarification. I will do it in separate sql query then.. :)